# Add lines to <head> when using Layouts in Iron Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

Using Iron Router and layouts, how can more lines be added to `<head>`? For example, adding the following code to `<head>`...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png">

<title>My Title</title>

<!-- Fonts from Google Fonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap that html code into `<head>` as you normally would. Do not put that into any template.

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png">

    <title>My Title</title>

    <!-- Fonts from Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Iron router does not interfere with this.

Comment: Where should this head go? Which file?

Comment: @Artem any .html file on client side will do.

Comment: Should it be a part of the template?